# Последовательность нажатия клавиш

Tags: c#, winforms

Как выполнить открытие формы, после нажатия определенной последовательности клавиш (стрелок) на клавиатуре? Прошу предоставить пример кода, в котором это реализовано.

Comment: Пробуйте Keyboardhook - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь сделать примитивно и просто хранить какой-нибудь int, а на каждое [нажатие клавишы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netframework-4.8) делать что-то наподобие:

```
private int _state=0;

private void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyChar)
    {
        case 'S' when _state == 2:
            _state = 0; 
            //наша последовательность символов (SOS) была нажата и мы можем открывать форму
            break;
        case 'O' when _state == 1:
            _state++; break;
        case 'S':
            _state = 1; break;
        default:
            _state = 0; break;
    }
}
```

А если захочешь сделать что-то более сложное и красивое с более продвинутыми условиями, то тебе надо посмотреть на конечные автоматы. [Глянуть можно туть](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B).

Comment: То, что вы написали, по сути и есть конечный автомат

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, но простой и без объяснений)